# Reason for enlightened men to awaken others

Tags: advaita, moksha

History has enlightened men who left the mitya and chose to stay with the truth perpetually and then there are other enlightened men who choose to work for waking up others. When they experience the world as a mitya why would they work for the betterment of men who are part of mitya. Working for the betterment of other men is like creating duality again.

Comment: that is advaita philosophy of mitya. maya is a better term to help understand in mode of duality.